# Masking Bits in n-party Garbled Circuit

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

Let us consider the scenario where there are n-1 garblers and a single evaluator. The garblers together need to generate a garbled circuit.  We use a distributed garbling protocol such as [BLO16] and hand over the inputs to evaluator.

Why during the computation are the masking bits needed? It is stated that each party can XOR its inputs and masking bits to create a masked input that reveals no information about input itself. What does this mean is not clear to me. The masking is not used in the 2 party setting of Yao garbled circuit. Why then for n-party?